# Setting up Dagger 2 and project organization in Android

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-2

I have a project organized in a way similar to below in Android studio:

- `:lib_commons`
- `:module_auth`
- `:app_demo`

`lib_commons` and `module_auth` are basically Android library projects.
`module_auth` is meant to be an independent, pluggable module to be attached to a couple of apps in the project. It contains an activity and a couple of fragments with injectable fields. Since Android would be in charge of managing these activities&fragments, I would have to inject the fields manually, something like `daggerComponent.inject(this)` in the activity

The application component, as well as other relevant modules currently reside in the various apps in the project (e.g app_demo), all to be instantiated by an Application subclass in the corresponding app.
This means I won't have access to the application component from `module_auth`, as a result, making injection impossible.
I have tried moving the dagger component to commons, but that would require it having a knowledge of all possible injection points, which would  be impossible since commons generally has no idea of the existence of any of these apps.

#### The question

What is a possible clean approach to organise the project such that I can access the application component from this module? Keeping in mind that the component would actually be instantiated in the `app_demo`'s Application object

In dagger 1, I could easily place the object graph in commons, and call `graph.inject(this)` from any registered class in the project. I would only have to load corresponding dagger modules separately for each app.
I could create an abstract Application in commons containing an abstract `getModules` method which would then be implemented in the apps. However the object graph is still the same one, and injection is pretty straight forward.

How do I acheive this in dagger 2?

Kindly advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I found a way to deal with this, with a little insight from this blogpost https://www.future-processing.pl/blog/dependency-injection-with-dagger-2/

This is my approach:

I have a component interface, say `AppComponent` in `:lib_commons` that is practically empty. This will serve as the super component for the concrete apps `:app_*`

I have an abstract `BaseApplication` in `:lib_commons`, something like

```
public abstract class BaseApplication<T extends AppComponent> extends Application {
    private T mComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mComponent = createComponent();
    }

    protected abstract T createComponent();

    public T getComponent() {
        return this.mComponent;
    }
}
```

The base activities, fragments etc look similar to this:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Get the Main Application component for dependency injection.
     */
    protected <C> C getAppComponent(Class<C> componentType) {
        return componentType.cast(((BaseApplication) getApplication()).getComponent());
    }
}
```

So, in the '`:module_*` where the actual components doesn't exist yet, I will create regular interfaces declaring the injection methods, so that injection is as simple as

```
getAppComponent(InjectionInterface.class).inject(this);
```

Finally, the `:app_*` modules would contain the actual component interface which will extend the super `AppComponent`  and every other corresponding `InjectionInterface` declared in the modules it depends on. I will then create a concrete Application class that extends `BaseApplication` and simply implements the abstract `createComponent` method, completing the injection circle.

Hope this helps someone.